# Randomly choose Index from Array, then display matching MC

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, removechild

So I have this code

```
function flip(e:MouseEvent)
{   
 //assign choice a random deck index.
    choice=int(deck[Math.round((Math.random()*deck.length))]);
    if(choice!=int(deck[9]))
    {
        //removeChild(MovieClip(e.target));

        //position firecard.        
        addChild(fire);
        fire.x=e.target.parent.x;
        fire.y=e.target.parent.y;

        //remove cardback
        e.target.parent.removeChild(MovieClip(e.target));       
        fire.parent.setChildIndex(fire,numChildren-2);
        trace(choice);
    }
    else if(choice==int(deck[9]))
    {
        trace(choice);
        water.x=e.target.parent.x;
        water.y=e.target.parent.y;
        e.target.parent.removeChild(MovieClip(e.target));
        water.parent.setChildIndex(water,numChildren-2);
    }

}
```

Comments explain pretty much what everything is supposed to do. Flip is called via a listener from a movieclip. Choice is a number that is randomly picked every time flip is called, and gets its value from a random index from the deck Array. Then regardless of the choice, the card that was clicked is removed and in its position is placed a card according to the choice var. However, two errors happen (none of which do something in the Compiler or Output).

1. The new cards that get created (fire) are also removed when I click on another card. I want them to stay on place.
2. The trace always prints a 0. Shouldn't it print like, anything from 0 to 9?

PS: Deck has 10 values. 9 of them are "fire", the last is "water". Choice starts with 0 initial value.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related, but I think you should be using Math.floor() instead of Math.round(). Using Math.round() results in the end numbers coming up less.

Comment: Math.round() is not about something coming up less it is about the way fractions are rounded wity Math.round(Math.random() * 10) you will have 0..10 inclusive meaning that your array will throw errors as for length of 10 it will have 0..9 indexes.

Comment: This is true, but I also meant to say due to this rounding, an 'end' number, say '0' would come up less as a result, since for 0 it has a range of only 0 to 0.4999 which gets rounded down to 0. After that 0.5 to 1.49999 would get rounded to '1' which results in '0' appearing less then other numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately, floor and round have the same result. 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are having string in the array("fire" and "water"). But you are typecasting this string to an int, so turns to 0. Just try without typecasting the value of the array.

```
function flip(e:MouseEvent)
{   
    //assign choice a random deck index.
    choice=deck[Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length)];
    if(choice != deck[9])
    {
        //removeChild(MovieClip(e.target));

        //position firecard.        
        addChild(fire);
        fire.x=e.target.parent.x;
        fire.y=e.target.parent.y;

        //remove cardback
        e.target.parent.removeChild(MovieClip(e.target));       
        fire.parent.setChildIndex(fire,numChildren-2);
        trace(choice);
    }
    else if(choice == deck[9])
    {
        trace(choice);
        water.x=e.target.parent.x;
        water.y=e.target.parent.y;
        e.target.parent.removeChild(MovieClip(e.target));
        water.parent.setChildIndex(water,numChildren-2);
    }

}
```

I didn't change anything other than removing the typecasting.

Comment: Typecasting, now that's an interesting word. However, I still only get 0s.

Comment: Sorry pal I forgot to say one more thing, ie. the declaration of the variable `choice`. I guess it was declared as `int`. Just make sure it is declared as `String` and then try, it will work for sure. Eg: `var choice:String;`

Comment: Actually, at first I thought this was a fluke as well, because it was always printing "fire", but after persistence I realized that it was because the odds were against me! (9 fires versus 1 water)...it works! Thanks, here you go, cookie :D

Answer (score 0):

```
function flip(e:MouseEvent)
{   
 //assign choice a random deck index.
    choice=Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length);
    if(choice!=9)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if(choice==9)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```